# Setting vsftpd for upload to public (http)

Tags: ftp, lamp, vsftpd

I just installed LAMP, vsftpd on Ubuntu server 11.04 64bits and I'm going to to adduser for ftp and let's users (in private LAN) upload files to public in private LAN such as http://local-server-ip/username/ could anyone recommend link or help me list these steps what I should to do? I try it before with Googling and I getting a lot of problems about permission after users add files into my specific path of apache2, when anyone open in browser it show "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /... on this server." then I re-install it. (for remove my dirty configuration).. *Sorry for my terrible English*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

Then, I'm using apache2 mod_userdir and public_html